# PowerShell script to export CSV with netBIOS name

Tags: powershell

I have a script that collect network information for a list of server in text file and export to CSV.
Everything works as expect but I need to get the host NETBIOS name from the the text file IP.
The text file contains servers IP address as xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx. I'm really weak when it comes to scripting. Below is the script. I really appreciate for the help from the expert in here.

```
$InputFile = "C:\servers.txt"
$CsvFile = "C:\results.csv"
$report = @()
ForEach($Computer in (gc -Path $InputFile)){
  If(Test-Connection -ComputerName $Computer -Count 1 -ea 0) {
    $Networks = Get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -ComputerName $Computer | ? {$_.IPEnabled}
    ForEach($Network in $Networks) {
      $IPAddress = $Network.IpAddress[0]
      $SubnetMask = $Network.IPSubnet[0]
      $DefaultGateway = $Network.DefaultIPGateway
    }
    $MACAddress = $Network.MACAddress
    $OutputObj = New-Object -Type PSObject
    $OutputObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name ComputerName -Value 
    $Computer.ToUpper()
    $OutputObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name IPAddress -Value 
    $IPAddress
    $OutputObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name SubnetMask -Value 
    $SubnetMask
    $OutputObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Gateway -Value 
    ($DefaultGateway -join ",")
    $OutputObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name MACAddress -Value 
    $MACAddress
    $Report += ,$OutputObj
  }
 }
 Write-Output $report
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your loop  :

```
$NetBiosName = Get-WmiObject  Win32_ComputerSystem -ComputerName $Computer | select -ExpandProperty name
$OutputObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "NetBiosName" -Value 
    $NetBiosName
```

PowerShell V2.0

```
    $InputFile = "c:\servers.txt"
    $CsvFile = "c:\results.csv"
    $report = @()
    ForEach($Computer in (gc -Path $InputFile)){
      If(Test-Connection -ComputerName $Computer -Count 1 -ea 0) {
        $Networks = Get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -ComputerName $Computer | ? {$_.IPEnabled}
        ForEach($Network in $Networks) {
          $IPAddress = $Network.IpAddress[0]
          $SubnetMask = $Network.IPSubnet[0]
          $DefaultGateway = $Network.DefaultIPGateway
        }

        $MACAddress = $Network.MACAddress
        $NetBiosName = Get-WmiObject  Win32_ComputerSystem -ComputerName $Computer | select -ExpandProperty name

        $OutputObj = New-Object -Type PSObject
        $OutputObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name NetBios -Value $NetBiosName
        $OutputObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name ComputerName -Value $Computer.ToUpper()
        $OutputObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name IPAddress -Value $IPAddress
        $OutputObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name SubnetMask -Value $SubnetMask
        $OutputObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Gateway -Value $DefaultGateway
        $OutputObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name MACAddress -Value $MACAddress
        $Report += ,$OutputObj
      }
     }
     Write-Output $report
```

Or this, but makes the list of properties in a random order... since PS v2.0 doesn't have the [ordered] thing.

```
    $InputFile = "c:\servers.txt"
    $CsvFile = "c:\results.csv"
    $report = @()
    ForEach($Computer in (gc -Path $InputFile)){
      If(Test-Connection -ComputerName $Computer -Count 1 -ea 0) {
        $Networks = Get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -ComputerName $Computer | ? {$_.IPEnabled}
        ForEach($Network in $Networks) {
          $IPAddress = $Network.IpAddress[0]
          $SubnetMask = $Network.IPSubnet[0]
          $DefaultGateway = $Network.DefaultIPGateway
        }

        $MACAddress = $Network.MACAddress
        $NetBiosName = Get-WmiObject  Win32_ComputerSystem -ComputerName $Computer | select -ExpandProperty name

        $Props = @{
                    NETBIOS      = $NetBiosName
                    ComputerName = $Computer.ToUpper()
                    IPAddress    = $IPAddress
                    SubnetMask   = $SubnetMask
                    Gateway      = ($DefaultGateway -join ",")
                    MACAddress   = $MACAddress
                }

        $OutputObj = New-Object -Type PSObject -Property $Props
        $Report += ,$OutputObj
      }
     }
     Write-Output $report
```

Or best if you have PowerShell v.3.0 or later.

```
    $InputFile = "c:\servers.txt"
    $CsvFile = "c:\results.csv"
    $report = @()
    ForEach($Computer in (gc -Path $InputFile)){
      If(Test-Connection -ComputerName $Computer -Count 1 -ea 0) {
        $Networks = Get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -ComputerName $Computer | ? {$_.IPEnabled}
        ForEach($Network in $Networks) {
          $IPAddress = $Network.IpAddress[0]
          $SubnetMask = $Network.IPSubnet[0]
          $DefaultGateway = $Network.DefaultIPGateway
        }

        $MACAddress = $Network.MACAddress
        $NetBiosName = Get-WmiObject  Win32_ComputerSystem -ComputerName $Computer | select -ExpandProperty name

        $Props = [ordered]@{
                    NETBIOS      = $NetBiosName
                    ComputerName = $Computer.ToUpper()
                    IPAddress    = $IPAddress
                    SubnetMask   = $SubnetMask
                    Gateway      = ($DefaultGateway -join ",")
                    MACAddress   = $MACAddress
                }

        $OutputObj = New-Object -Type PSObject -Property $Props
        $Report += ,$OutputObj
      }
     }
     Write-Output $report
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Robbie. I added Get-WmiObject Win32_ComputerSystem -Computer $Computer | Select -ExpandProperty name as you suggested but it still return with IP not computer NetBIOS name :(

Comment: I might have put the code that you suggested in the wrong place. What should I put that line of code to the script? I'm learning and have a hard time. :(

Comment: @Nguyen, this is the solution.

Comment: Thanks a lot, JPBlanc. However, when I run the script I got an error:

Comment: "Unable to find [ordered]: make sure that the assembly containing this type is loaded. At C:\script_file: 16 char 27                                                          $Prop = [Ordered] <<<< ${                                                                                + CategoryInfo  : InvalidOperation: (ordering:String) [], RuntimException  + FullyQualifiedErrorId: TypeNotFound

Comment: New-Object: Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Property'. The argument is null or empty. Supply an argument that is not null or empty and then try again.                                                                                       At C:\Script_file:25 char:57

Comment: I really appreciate for your help, JP

Comment: You must be using an older version of PowerShell that does not have the allow the [ordered] in front of the hash table, you can remove the ordered part, but now the order of the properties will not be as listed or go back to the old way. I'll update the original answer in just a sec.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Robbie. I really appreciated. I'm new to the company and by running $PSVersionTable, it shows the servers still on PS v.2

Comment: @Nguyen If you are using or going to be using powershell.  I would suggest that you go watch the MVA Getting Started with PowerShell JumpStart.  Its an awesome free course with the inventor of PowerShell. https://www.microsoftvirtualacademy.com/en-us/training-courses/getting-started-with-powershell-3-0-jump-start-8276  And a book called Learn Windows PowerShell 3 in a month of lunches.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, Robbie. I purchased 2 books Learning PowerShell 3 in a month or lunches and Tool making in a month lunches not too long ago and still try to find time to learn it. I will looking into MVA. Again, thanks for your suggestion. :)

Comment: Thank you very much, Robbie. I really really really appreciated. I wish I can be as best as scripting as you someday. :)